# How to execute PowerShell scripts in Node.js using child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, child-process

I want to create a locally running website that works with the username and password entered       by the user. This website will retrieve the password expiration time from the Active Directory based on the user's information. After executing PowerShell commands using child_process, I want to send the results back to the user. However, I'm encountering the 'require is not defined' error in the browser. I have started learning Express.js for this purpose, but I'm not sure if I need to save the node.js folder with child_process in a different location or include the child_process commands within Express.js. I'm unsure how to use the child_process module in the browser. Additionally, I would like to know how to deploy this project on IIS. Thank you in advance.

```
`const express = require('express');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/getADUserInfo', (req, res) =\> {
const { username } = req.body;
```

```
const psScript = \`
$adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity "${username}" -Properties PasswordLastSet, AccountExpirationDate, LastLogonDate, LastBadPasswordAttempt, DisplayName, Mail

    $userInfo = @{
      "Kullanici Adi" = $adUser.SamAccountName
      "Ad" = $adUser.GivenName
      "Soyad" = $adUser.Surname
      "Sifre Son Degistirme Tarihi" = $adUser.PasswordLastSet
      "Hesap Son Kullanma Tarihi" = $adUser.AccountExpirationDate
      "Son Giris Tarihi" = $adUser.LastLogonDate
      "Son Hatali Sifre Denemesi Tarihi" = $adUser.LastBadPasswordAttempt
      "Görünen İsim" = $adUser.DisplayName
      "E-posta Adresi" = $adUser.Mail
    }
    
    ConvertTo-Json $userInfo

\`;

const child = spawn('powershell.exe', \['-Command', '-'\]);

child.stdin.write(psScript);
child.stdin.end();

let output = '';

child.stdout.on('data', (data) =\> {
output += data.toString();
});

child.stderr.on('data', (data) =\> {
console.error('Powershell Errors: ' + data);
});

child.on('exit', () =\> {
console.log('Powershell Script finished');
res.send(output);
});
});

app.listen(port, () =\> {
console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});\``
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.